# Set values with conditions LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, repository

I'm selecting some data from table `A` with a column `value` and type which have relationship with table `B` where there is a column `coef` that contains `(-1,0,1)`
When retrieving from `A` I want to multiply the `value` with `coef`.

Comment: Please post your model

Comment: OK, that's what you want. Now what is you actual issue with your current code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var result = from a in tableA
             join b in tableB on a.Key = b.ForeignKey
             select new 
             {
                 Value = a.value * b.coef
             };
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a LINQ expression to do it in one line:

```
dt.Rows.ForEach(x => x["value"] = (double)x["value"] * (double)x["coef"]);
```

or you could just add another column to the DataTable:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Result", typeof(decimal));
dt["result"] = "value * coef";
```

Comment: Since the OP specified he was using Entity Framework, there is no such DataTable/Rows concept.

Comment: And `ForEach()` is not LINQ. It's standard instance method on `List<T>`